# View not listing the contents of database in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

My sqlite3 database has contacts of people in the following format:-

id first_name last_name location city country phone_number email

I have filled two entries into the database.

My model class is as follows:-

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

My controller is as follows:-

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @contacts=Contact.find(:all)

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contacts }
    end
  end


  def show
    @contacts=Contact.find(:all)
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

My view is as follows:-

```
<h1>My Contact List</h1>

<% if @contacts.blank? %>
<p>No contacts to display</p>

<% else %>
    <ul id="contacts">
    <% @contacts.each do |c| %>
    <li>
       <% link_to c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name, :action =>'show', :id =>c.id  -%>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

When i run start the Webrick server to view localhost:3000/contact/index i just get "My Contact List" with 2 blank list items and not the actual contents from the database.

How should i proceed? I am not able to find out my mistake.

Comment: Ensure that you actually have correct records in the database to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to use the equal sign. so in your view do the following

```
<%= link_to c.first_name + ' ' + c.last_name, :action =>'show', :id =>c.id  %>
```

Comment: Equal sign was missing indeed.Thank you so much!